# How to download ParseKit for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, parsing, parser-generator, parsekit

Really basic (and probably quite idiotic) question but I'm not familiar with this procedure of downloading source code. Even if you've never download this you may be able to point out what I'm missing.

I'm trying to get the ParseKit parser generator for use with my iPhone app:

The instructions say I need a project file called 'ParseKit.xcodeproj':

http://parsekit.com/iphone.html

The link below takes me to the source files, but I can't see where to get the actual project file:

http://code.google.com/p/todparsekit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftags%2Frelease-1.5-tag

ParseKit.xcodeproj is on the left but I can't download it itself, project.pbxproj opens up to contain some source code. How can I get the project file itself?

Apologies for the question but the whole thing seems painfully unobvious, why not just provide a download link? I must be missing something...

Thanks!

Comment: `svn checkout http://todparsekit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/todparsekit-read-only`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check out the code using svn.
http://subversion.tigris.org/